# How to check if MongoDB server is running in pc

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I wanted to check if my MongoDB server is running.

I am following a tutorial in thinkster.io about the [MEAN stack tutorial.](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#creating-schemas-with-mongoose)

> Our first step in making a persistent data store is to configure our data models. To do this, we are going to be adding a schema layer on top of MongoDB using a nice library called Mongoose. Before we begin, let's make sure our MongoDB server is running.

I tried many things but I didn't know what to do. My main question is whether you have to start the server and then open another cmd and type
`mongod &` or
stop the server and then type
`mongod &` or
when the server is running just type
`mongod &` in the same cmd without stopping the server or starting another cmd.

Comment: I opened my cmd when to my root directory called flapper-news and then I did this command called 'npm start' to create a server in http://localhost:3000. It was working fine but when I went to the next heading 'Creating Schemas With Mongoose' ( https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#creating-schemas-with-mongoose ) I had a problem with that first command. I tried many stuff but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Have you [installed the MongoDB server](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

let me describe you in a clear way when you type `mongod` in cmd it will start your `mongod server` it means your database service is started

now for connecting to mongo you should open new `cmd` and type `mongo` it will behave as a client.now you can query in mongo like this

`show collections`

`show dbs`

Comment: My error is `'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`.

Comment: simple write `mongod` not mongod &.if the result is same it means mongodb is not installed or configure in your system

Comment: How do I download MongoDB properly then? If you think I am wrong. Last question should I `mongod` on my root directory or somewhere else?

Comment: Muhammed com'n can you please do it quickly as I need to continue my project.

Comment: install `mongodb` from there https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/?jmp=footer if you have `linux` then install `mongo` on your root as if u are using windows install on `program files` and give a path in `environment variable` so it recognize `mongod` otherwise for running `mongod` you should go to that folder

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad when you say ''mongod in cmd will start your mongod server'', then please tell me what is the difference between commands `mongod`  and `service mongod start`?

Answer (score -1):

To verify if MongoDB is installed correctly, open the Command Prompt and execute the following command:

`mongod --version`

[image]